# referencing Google Play Library on a Qt Project

Tags: android, c++, qt, google-cloud-messaging

I am making an app in Qt for Android and i want it to use the Google Cloud Messaging service for the push notifications. But i am having a really hard time figuring out how to install all this with Qt.

The documentation says that i need to reference the Google Play Library to my project.
https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

I am assuming i need to do all this via the command-line because i am not using the android SDK. So following the docs

```
To add a reference to a library project, navigate to the <sdk>/tools/ directory and use this command:

android update project \
--target <target_ID> \
--path path/to/your/project
--library path/to/library_projectA
```

So i tried executing:

```
C:\Users\01222_000\Documents\android-sdk\tools>android update project --target "
C:\Users\01222_000\Desktop\app1" --path C:\Users\01222_000\Desktop\app1 --librar
y C:\Users\01222_000\QtProjects\google-play-services_lib
```

it gave me this error:

```
Error: Target id 'C:\Users\01222_000\Desktop\app1' is not valid. Use 'android.ba
t list targets' to get the target ids.
```

So i used android.bat to check which target id's are available:

```
C:\Users\01222_000\Documents\android-sdk\tools>android.bat list targets
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-22"
     Name: Android 5.1.1
     Type: Platform
     API level: 22
     Revision: 2
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, W
XGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : android-tv/armeabi-v7a, android-tv/x86, default/armeabi-v7a, default
/x86, default/x86_64
----------
id: 2 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:22"
     Name: Google APIs
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 1
     Description: Android + Google APIs
     Based on Android 5.1.1 (API level 22)
     Libraries:
      * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
          API for USB Accessories
      * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
          Collection of video effects
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, W
XGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : google_apis/armeabi-v7a, google_apis/x86, google_apis/x86_64
```

**Could someone point out to me what i am doing wrong? Or am i following the wrong direction alltogether?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use one of the target ids given by "android.bat list targets". That is, 1 or "android-22" for Android 5.1.1, 2 or or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:22" for Google APIs.

An example(assume you will use 1 or "android-22"), run:

```
android update project --target 1 --path C:\Users\01222_000\Desktop\app1 --library C:\Users\01222_000\QtProjects\google-play-services_lib
```

or

```
android update project --target "android-22" --path C:\Users\01222_000\Desktop\app1 --library C:\Users\01222_000\QtProjects\google-play-services_lib
```

Comment: i see, now its giving me this error: 

Error: C:\Users\01222_000\QtProjects\app1 is not a valid project (AndroidManifest.xml not found).

Comment: i fixxed it, i copied an androidmanifest.xml file from the library folder of GCM